# Rasterizing Delaunay triangulation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, triangulation, delaunay, rasterizing

I have computed a Delaunay triangulation using `DelaunayTri()` in `Matlab R2010b`. Now I would like to burn a subset of the triangles (i.e. 12200 triangles) into a matrix (Raster). Is there any fast/efficient way of doing this?

I have tried using both `poly2mask()` and `inpolygon()` to select pixels inside the triangles, but this is rather slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this fast solution:

```
qrypts=[xgridcoords, ygridccords]; %grid x and y coordinates
triids = pointLocation(dt, qrypts); %associate each grid point to its Delaunay triangle
Lia = ismember(triids,dtsubset); %keep subset of points contained in the desired triangles (dtsubset contains the indices of desired triangles)
IM=false(size(grid)); 
IM(Lia)=1;
```